# VSCode stop automatic line break (new line) after semicolon

Tags: visual-studio-code, formatting, line-breaks

I am having an unpleasant issue in VSCode with JavaScript formatting which slows me down during coding.

I use format on Type and in JavaScript files (I believe TypeScript too) the semicolon character is a trigger. I am fine with it triggering, but I do not like the end result.

After typing a semicolon character, a new line is automatically added after it, resulting in basically the opposite of formatted code. Please see the behavior below:

[image: behavior example]

(in the above, I wanted the if condition to be all inline)

Following are some of the custom editor settings that I have:

```json
{
    "editor.insertSpaces": false,
    "editor.formatOnPaste": true,
    "editor.formatOnType": true,
    "javascript.format.semicolons": "insert",
    "[javascriptreact]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.typescript-language-features"
    },
    "[javascript]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.typescript-language-features"
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any idea why this happens, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue but with CSS File,
I couldn't find a specific configuration that stop breaking the line after the semicolon.
The only solution I found was changing the CSS editor formatter from `vscode.css-language-features to prettier`
(I'm using prettier but a different formatter might also work)

```
//"editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.css-language-features"        
"editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
```

Hope this can help..

Answer (score -1):

Verify your file **settings.json** in `/home/'user-name'/.config/Code/`

and change this lines to **false**

> ```
>     "editor.formatOnSave": false,
>     "editor.formatOnType": false,
> ```

Comment: I have stated in my question that I use the "format on type" setting (set to true) and that I'm not willing to give it up. But thanks for trying.